# PHP file_get_contents with variables

Tags: php, variables, file-get-contents

I have a function:

```
myfunc () {
   $a = "John";
   $str = "Hello $a, how are you today?"
   return $str;
}

echo myfunc(); //Hello John, how are you today?
```

I want to save all the sentenses in that function to another file, because their length is too long to put it in my function.

```
myfunc () {
  $a = "John";
  $str = file_get_contents("inc_file.html");
  return $str;
}
```

inc_file.html:

```
Hello $a, how are you today?
```

But it didn't return as I expected. The variable $a is not changed to John.
Please help me !
Thanks

Comment: No, I don't want to save file with some functions. I create the html file manually. The php code only for reading and displaying contents in html files

Answer (score 3):

All that `file_get_contents()` does is return the contents of the file, as the function name suggests. It does not parse the contents which is what happens with a string in `"`s.

Using `str_replace()` on the returned file contents seems to achieve what you want.

```
$str = file_get_contents("inc_file.html");
$str = str_replace('$a', 'John', $str);
return $str;
```

If you wanted to replace multiple 'variables' you can pass arrays to `str_replace`, for example

```
$search = [$a, $b];
$replace = ['John', 'Brian'];

$str = file_get_contents("inc_file.html");
$str = str_replace($search, $replace, $str);
return $str;
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: It's fine. But I have so many many variables in my func. I defined all these variables at the code before. And I must rewrite all of them in the str_replace function ? I really want it's auto detect the exist variable without replacing.

Answer (score 1):

Line `$str = file_get_contents("inc_file.html");` just **gets file contents**. It **doesn't evaluate** this contents and **doesn't replaces** vars with its' values.

Suppose, what would happen if file will be huge of there will be some specific text about php variables?

They all should be replaced with some values? I suppose not. So, you just have a string with symbols like `$a`.

And if you have to replace something in a string - use `str_replace`, simple code is:

```
function myfunc () {
    $a = "John";
    $str = file_get_contents("inc_file.html");
    return str_replace('$a', $a, $str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have is fine, you can just use a `preg_replace_callback()` or in this case `str_replace()` to do what you want. Just do some adjustments:

**HTML:**

```
"Hello ~val~, how are you today?"
```

**PHP**

```
function myfunc ($a)
    {
        $str = str_replace('~val~',$a,file_get_contents("inc_file.html"));
        return $str;
    }

echo myfunc('John');
```

Simple `preg_replace_callback()` example:

```
function myfunc ($string,$a)
    {

        $str = preg_replace_callback('/(~[^~]{1,}~)/',function($v) use (&$a)
            {
                return array_shift($a);
            },$string);

        return $str;
    }

$string = "hello my name is ~name~. I come from ~city~";
echo myfunc($string,array('John','San Francisco'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can to include .php file but wit .html isn`t works because you include html not php code. If you make code and your file like this:

```
<?php
function myfunc() 
{
  $a = "John";
  $str = file_get_contents("inc_file.php");
  return $str;
}
?>
```

inc_file.php:

```
Hello <?php echo $a; ?>, how are you today?
```

Comment: It didn't work. I think because the function "file_get_contents" not pass the variables. But if I use "include" instead, it didn't return value for my variable $str

Answer (score 0):

here's a method that replaces any matching variables from the loaded file string. It's a modified version of code from the link below. I modified it to check for string type. It assumes the variables are global.

[How can I output this dynamic data without eval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472792/how-can-i-output-this-dynamic-data-without-eval)

```
function interpolate( $string ){
foreach ($GLOBALS as $name => $value){
    // avoid array to string and object conversion errors
  if(is_string($value)){
    $string = str_replace( '$'.$name, $value, $string );
  }
}
$string = preg_replace( '/[$]\\w+/', '', $string );
return $string;
}
$emailTemplate = file_get_contents('inc_file.html');
$emailTemplate = interpolate($emailTemplate);
echo $emailTemplate;
```

I found this after searching for a way to do it without eval() like shown below:

```
$emailTemplate = file_get_contents('inc_file.html');
$emailTemplate = htmlentities($emailTemplate);
eval("\$emailTemplate = \"$emailTemplate\";");
echo html_entity_decode($emailTemplate) ;
```