# lighttpd and fastcgi.map-extension detection / content negotiation on rewritten "clean" URLs with no file extensions?

Tags: php, url-rewriting, fastcgi, lighttpd, clean-urls

My current website uses PHP to build and output HTML content to the browser specified by rewritten "clean" urls.

```
url.rewrite-once = (
"^/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$" => "/index.php?section=$1",
"^/([-a-zA-Z0-9/]+)/([-a-zA-Z0-9/]+)$" => "/index.php?section=$1&article=$2" 
)
```

index.php simply calls my functions to build and output content depending on the variables:

```
http://domain.com/some-section/this-is-an-article/
```

At present this is just flat HTML output, but I am wanting to now in the flat output include PHP, mainly for PHP include calls when the page is loaded in the browser:

```
<h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
<?php include_once('example.php') ;?>
<p>Dolar sit amet.</p>
```

I simply thought I could map HTML through php as such:

```
fastcgi.map-extensions = ( ".html" => ".php" )
```

But because my URLs do not physically have file extensions and nor does any physical rewritten page with extension actually exist, fastcgi cannot map anything.

I have tested that fastcgi works by simply creating a .html file with embedded PHP and it is parsed correctly, so I know .html file extensions are being mapped through fastcgi.

My question is simply (or not so) how would one get fastcgi/lighttpd to map my outputted content through PHP if it does not have an extension?

Comment: If you outputted content, didn't you output it thru php? If content is displayed, it is already processed via the server

Comment: Well, basically I built myself a simple flat-file CMS. 

`http://domain.com/some-section/this-is-an-article/`

Actually looks for `this-is-an-article` a flat file located in the physical `some-section` directory in my webroot. My PHP function then reads this file and builds an HTML page from it (including headers/css/menus etc). So basically I want to embed some PHP code in the flat file which will also be in the outputted flat HTML file. Simply the same way you would embed `<?php echo 'hello' ;?>` in HTML page and push it through PHP to be interpreted when you load the page in the browser.

Comment: After spending hours reading I finally realised that you can't evaluate PHP after the page is served, as PHP executes on the server not the browser, hence the extension handling. So my issue is basically now how to evaluate the content which is currently just printed. Any ideas how to do this well without resorting to `eval()`?

Comment: Spotted this helpful conversation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326446/php-templating-with-custom-tags-is-this-a-legit-use-of-eval